# In Memory OLTP causing OOM Issue in SQL Server even though no data in In Memory OLTP Table

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-optimized-tables, in-memory-database

We have only 1 memory optimized table in each database and there are total 10 databases as such. This table is completely empty. But still we can see in DBCC MEMORYSTATUS Output that In memory OLTP is consuming 7.68 GB out of 13 GB that has been assigned to SQL Server.

MEMORYCLERK_XTP (node 0)                         KB

---

VM Reserved                                       0
VM Committed                                      0
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
SM Reserved                                       0
SM Committed                                      0
Pages Allocated                             8055696 -- 7.68 GB

[image]

Sometimes CHECKPOINT is also not running because of OOM situation.

Other than restarting SQL Service, is there any other solution to resolve this issue?

SQL Server Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU12) (KB4536648) - 13.0.5698.0 (X64)   Feb 15 2020 01:47:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1):

It's a best practice to use a Resource Pool if running EE, that might help in this case. Also, garbage collection does not occur unless there is memory pressure/activity.